# Ubuntu black screen of death, AMD RX560

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, graphics, amd-graphics

Whenever I turn on my computer it goes into an endless black screen of death which stalls forever. This appears to be an issue with the graphics drivers or grub's parameters.

Attempted:

- nomodeset (Boots but no drivers of course hence bad performance)
- Installing pro and normal amd drivers (Continues to resolve to black screen)
- Looking for errors related to graphics, couldn't find any (Probably looking in the wrong places)
- Rebooting multiple times and waiting long periods of time
- Installing 18.10 version of Ubuntu
- Multiple graphic driver PPA repos

Setup:

- Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 (Attempted 18.10, same results)
- Installed through Wubiuefi
- AMD RX560 ([18.40 drivers](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-560))
- CPU - Ryzen 5 1600 3.2 ghz stock OC to 4.0 ghz
- MOBO - B350 Tomahawk
- 8gb ddr4 2144 mhz oc to 3000 mhz

Unfortuantly I don't really know how to proceed with this issue, any help or thoughts is greatly appreciated :3

Comment: I actually found this post while I was in the store, considering the purchase. Great question.

Answer (score 0):

## I have the same GPU, running beautifully on 18.04, here's what I did:

*This is a great question, it's nice to know what GPUs work with Ubuntu.*

My set-up: I had a pre-existing Ubuntu 18.04 installation with a 64 bit Intel quad core on a Windows 7 machine. Everything was working before, then I did *Method 1* (below), then the new GPU worked with no re-install of Ubuntu, but movies wouldn't play. ***In order to make movies play, I had to re-install Ubuntu fresh, after seating the GPU on the motherboard.***

### Do you really need drivers?

1. Yes. But, you can either install them manually after Ubuntu is already installed (buggy) OR you can just get them when you install Ubuntu by having the GUP already on the motherboard.
2. "Open Source" drivers come a. with the AMD driver download (*Driver's First*, below) and b. when you install Ubuntu. You only need to download drivers with *Method 1*, *Method 2* will automatically download the Open Source drivers when you install Ubuntu.

## Method 1: No Ubuntu re-install, can't play video, normal desktop works great:

### I. Drivers First

1. Download the driver's you need ***before*** you change-out your working/inferior GPU. I found it at the the [AMD Radeon RX560 download page](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-560). (A great driver website, btw, should be easy to find stuff!)
2. Install the driver per the instructions:

   - In the unpacked directory: `./amdgpu-install -y`
   - Wait a while at about 72% since it needs to build something, it didn't break, be patient
   - That should be it, you're done
3. Per [this post at amd.com](https://community.amd.com/thread/228624), Open Source AMD drivers are best for most uses, including gaming and video. The "Pro" line (as opposed to the Open Source line) is for things like CAD. You probably don't need Pro unless someone with a master's degree looked at your face and told you so, really.
4. If you have special "Pro" GPU needs, follow the instructions that come with the download (use a web browser to open this file in the unpacked directory: `doc/index.html`)

## Method 2: Re-install Ubuntu, so you don't need drivers

### I. Back up your stuff

- ***Before*** setting the GUP onto the motherboard, do whatever backups you do before re-installing Ubuntu. That usually involves backing up your /home folder and whatnot, you know.
- Once you seat the new GPU on the motherboard, you won't be able to boot to an already-installed Ubuntu.

## Methods 1 & 2 *(continued...)*

### II. Motherboard Precautions

*Before seating (changing) any new hardware cards on the motherboard, including RAM, disk drives, GPU card, etc...*

1. Power off the PC
2. Turn-off the power supply switch in back
3. Then unplug the power supply

*If you add/remove cards on the motherboard while it is plugged into power, even if powered off, the smallest cross in connection points can fry the entire motherboard, which I've seen happen. This could cause your "Black screen of death", a permanent and expensive dilemma.*

### III. Change-Out the GPU

*NOT to be silly: "Did you plug it in?" is a troubleshooting question that solves many hardware problems! "Did you try replacing the cable?" solves almost as many.*

1. Be gentle, do things correctly and mindfully, no "forcing"
2. Check that the GPU card fits everywhere nicely
3. Plug the video cables into the back
4. Plug back in the power cable
5. Turn-on the power supply switch
6. Boot the PC

### IV. Additional Settings

- My BIOS clock was reset, I set the time and saved BIOS (it kept bugging me every reboot until I save-exited)
- I did NOT reset BIOS settings, only set the time and save-exited
- I had to reboot from Ubuntu once for the PC to recognize which monitor I was using
- Some of my custom desktop settings returned to default, so I changed them back

### V. Conclusion

This GPU really works great with Ubuntu! It's beautiful, silent, and fast—but you need to install it correctly.

Make sure you follow all hardware precautions, should be common sense stuff.

Comment: This might not address *all* hardware questions, but I have this GPU working, so I'm posting an answer from experience. :-) I hope someone with a more identical hardware config could pipe in also.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and disabled AMD virtualization and iommu on my BIOS.
That solved the problem.

However, in my case, I was using the AMD card as the second.